# How to find data matching the search in any field of the column in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, search, eloquent

i'm trying get data from a table which is called item and i want to bring the items that contains the search string that the user searches for example the user searches "active" so it will go the the table pick up any data that's field contain the word "active". i tried to do it with this piece of code but it does not work.

```
Route::get('/data', function () {
$items = Item::where('status', 'Like', 'active')->get();
dd($items); });
```

Any one has a solution?

Comment: $items = Item::where('status', 'like', '%active%')->get();

Comment: Thanks but it only searches for 1 field in this case the field status is there a way which will serach through all the fieds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
$items = Item::where('status', 'like', '%active%')->get();
```

To search multiple columns you can do `orwhere` like below

```
 $items = Item::where('status', 'like', '%active%')
->orWhere('column2', 'like', '%active%')
->orWhere('column3', 'like', '%active%')
->get();
```

or

```
$columns=['col1','col2','col3'];

 $items = Item::query();
foreach($columns as $column){
$items->orWhere($column,'like','%active%')
}
$result=$items->get();
```

or

```
 $columns=['col1','col2','col3'];
    
     $items = Item::where(function($query)use($columns){
 foreach($columns as $column){
   $query->orWhere($column,'like','%active%')
    }
})->get();
```